# How do I make the refresh rate stick in aticonfig?

Tags: 12.04, ati

So, I have an HTPC hooked up to my TV. I can set the refresh rate to 60 Hz through the catalyst control center and 60 Hz is fine for me), but if I reboot, it goes back to 30 Hz. How do I get this to stick? I could hack it with an xrandr script, but I'd rather not.